# Using a jQuery selector and each

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to truncate a string to a certain pixel width. The *best* way I discovered is through using jQuery's selector and possibly using each on the results. My attempt is at http://jsbin.com/umawi/edit. I haven't done much jQuery at all, and any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: I need to do this for inline elements and not block elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jquery for this.

```
<div class="truncate">Truncate some test</div>
```

with:

```
div.truncate { width: 100px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; }
```

as just one simple example. You can even add:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

but [support is limited](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html).

It's also worth noting that this only works (well) on block display elements, not inline and not table cells so if this is in a table you'll need to do:

```
<td><div>...</div></td>
```

because otherwise you won't get the desired results.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I tried this before, but didn't know I needed the nowrap and hidden overflow.

Comment: What if I want to do this to inline elements? Say, a part of an unordered list? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: List elements aren't inline. But no you can't apply overflow to inline (well you can, it just won't do what you want).